# Ruby Post returns 404 URL Not found while curl works fine

Tags: ruby, rest, gitlab-ci, put, gitlab-api

I'm trying to write some Ruby code to update GitLab CI/CD variables using the REST endpoint [update variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable). When I perform a curl with the same path, the same private token, and the same `--form` data it updates the variable as expected. When I use the Ruby code that I put together based on reading stackoverflow and the [net::http](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) docs, it fails with a 404 URL not found.

I can use a similar piece of code to [*create* a new CI/CD variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#create-variable) successfully. I can also delete an existing variable, and re-create it, but it I would like to know the mistake I am making in the update call.

Can someone point out what I did wrong?

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

token = File.read(__dir__ + '/.gitlab-token').chomp

host = 'https://gitlab.com/'
variables_path = 'api/v4/projects/123456/variables'
env_var = 'MY_VAR'
update_uri = URI(host + variables_path + '/' + env_var)
# I've written the above this way because my actual code 
# has a delete and create in order to "update" the variable

response = Net::HTTP.start(update_uri.host, update_uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  update_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(update_uri)
  update_request['PRIVATE-TOKEN'] = token
  form_data = [
    ['value', 'a new value']
  ]
  update_request.set_form(form_data, 'multipart/form-data')
  response = http.request(update_request)
  response.body
end
```

Comment: BTW: I asked this question rather than in the GitLab issues as I think this is a problem with my Ruby, not their API endpoint.

Comment: the api [update-variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable) is `PUT`, but your request is `Net::HTTP::Post`

Comment: D'oh. Thank you @LamPhan! Do you want to put that as an answer so I accept it and you get points?

Comment: thanks ! but i think it's minor and a comment is enough.